# setting up Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I am on 22.04

I have a headset, and I can see that the system is picking it up, but I cannot figure out how to set it up. I just get a message "Not Set Up"

I can connect to my phoe, but when I disconnect fromt the phone the headset disappears from the list, and instead the phone shows up as a bluetooch device.

When I pair the headset with the phone gain, the headset shows up in devices again.

Comment: Use the terminal to run `bluetoothctl scan on` and check whether your device is listed there. You might need to install **BlueZ** using `apt install bluez` to run the command.